# Let D be the region enclosed by the polar curve $r=1+cos\theta$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Assume D is a thin plate of constant density $ρ$. Find the coordinates of the center of mass of the plate. You should compute $m$ and $Mx$ entirely by hand; you may use Mathematica to finish off the $θ$ integral for $My$.

I started this problem by graphing the curve to get an idea of how it looks. However, I got stuck when it came to setting up the double integral.

Comment: I think you need to share with us what you have done and show where you got stuck.

Comment: I got stuck setting up the double integral to find the total mass. I was not sure how to go about getting this integral set up.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure exactly what the question entails.  But the function $r=1+cos\theta$ is symmetric, in that it has a mirror reflection about the $x$-axis.  It also encloses a region of constant density.  So, the centre of mass is located somewhere along the $x$-axis, ie. $\bar{y} = 0$.

Next, calculate in the usual way $\bar{x}=\frac{M_y}{M}$ where $$M=\rho \int_{0}^{2\pi} (1+cos\theta) d\theta$$and $$M_{y}=\rho \int_{0}^{2\pi} (1+cos\theta)^{2} sin\theta \text{  }d\theta dr$$

Comment: why the d(theta)dr at the end? Shouldnt it be just D(theta)?